# slick carousel not working in bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

I'm trying to navigate 2 slick carousels using bootstrap dropdown menu with tab functionality. Initially the news wrapper will be hidden. The idea is to navigate the slick carousel in two ways. Fist one is using dropdown menu and the second option is using button show hide method. So please check this link http://meritdesigns.in/news/ for better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted any code to go along with this or even any description of exactly what the problem is so it's hard to tell what is causing your issue. As a quick fix to overwrite the inline CSS for the featured news slider the JS is producing from your plugin, here is a CSS fix, although a solution without using '!important' would be much better:

```
.slick-track {
  width: 10000px !important;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  width: 300px !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your valuable answer. I tried your css and it shows 6 items but I need 4 items to be shown, also It will mess up while resize the window. So I cannot give that css. The objective is to show the news slider in tow ways as I mentioned in my question. If you want I will fiddle the code.